# how to get values of keys with @ sign in keys javascript

Tags: javascript

the data for example is

var data = {
    "@timestamp": "2018-05-11 01:34"
}

I've tried console.log(data.['@timestamp'])

but this gives an unexpected token error

Comment: Use dot notation or bracket notation, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
var data = { "@timestamp": "2018-05-11 01:34" }
console.log(data['@timestamp'])
```

You have typo with extra `.`?